# QT scrollbar does not appear when the size of the content exceeds the window size

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, scrollbar

I'm working with qt, and I'm creating dynamically the objects of the following pictures (each timeline is a widget).
The structure is that I'm adding this widget to a verticalLayout, that is the widget contained by the scrollArea.
But unfortunately the scrollbar does not appear when instead it should be present:
[image]
If I increase the size of the window, the content is shown correctly:
[image]
But since the number of timelines created inside the window can be greater than the screen size, I need a scrollbar. What could be the problem? that

EDIT: Some source code, the constructor of the main window: some code is not present because it is created with QTCreator

```
Schedule::Schedule(QString pathname, QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Schedule)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->scrollArea->setLayout(ui->pageLayout);

    traceParser parser(pathname);
    parser.readJson();
    ArchitectureParameter arch = parser.getArchParam();

    QString taskName;


    for(std::list<QString>::iterator taskNameIter = parser.getTaskNames().begin();
        taskNameIter != parser.getTaskNames().end(); taskNameIter++)
    {
        taskName = *taskNameIter;
        TaskSchedule *t = new TaskSchedule(this , taskName, 80, arch.nCPU(), arch.maxTime(),
                                          parser.getExecList(taskName), parser.getTaskSimpleEventsMap(taskName));
        t->resize(600, t->height());
        t->resize(600, t->width());
        ui->pageLayout->addWidget(t);

    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like the widgets on the upper picture overlap each other adjusting to the height of the main window. Can you reduce the code to the example which we can discuss?

Comment: Sorry I haven't understand which code should I reduce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this happens because you set the layout on the scrollArea. Here is the fast snippet which works for me:

```
QWidget* testWidget = new QWidget;
QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout;
QStringList strings;
strings << "asdfasd" << "asdffdfd" << "asdvvsdf" << "asdfccasdf";
Q_FOREACH(QString string, strings){
    TagButton* btn = new TagButton();
    btn->setText(string);
    layout->addWidget(btn);
}
testWidget->setLayout(layout);

QScrollArea* scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
scrollArea->setWidget(testWidget);

scrollArea->show();
```

Notice that I am setting the layout on the testWidget and then setWidget on scrollArea